# addQueue.leaseTasks(options) returns empty params []

Tags: google-cloud-tasks

addQueue.leaseTasks(options) returns empty params []

I created a queue added data when I try to get the data out TaskHandle has a empty parms[]

//Add to queue
    Queue addQueue = queueService.addQueue();
    TaskHandle task = addQueue.add(mapFundToTask(fund));

```
private TaskOptions mapFundToTask(Fund fund){
    return TaskOptions.Builder.withMethod(Method.PULL)
    .tag("FundTask")
    .param("ClientId", fund.getClientId())
    .param("FundId", fund.getFundId())
    .param("FundName", fund.getFundName());
}

// Get data from queue
Queue addQueue = queueService.addQueue();
int count = 2;
Long leaseDuration = 1000L;
LeaseOptions options = LeaseOptions.Builder
            .withTag("FundTask")
            .countLimit(count)
            .leasePeriod(leaseDuration, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
List<TaskHandle> tasks = addQueue.leaseTasks(options);
```

Comment: <queue-entries>
    <queue>
        <name>default</name>
        <rate>10/s</rate>
        <mode>push</mode>
    </queue>
    <queue>
        <name>add</name>
        <mode>pull</mode>
        <!-- Should set backend host.
            <target></target>
        -->
    </queue>
    <queue>
        <name>delete</name>
        <mode>pull</mode>
        <!-- Should set backend host.
            <target></target>
        -->
    </queue>
    <queue>
        <name>pull</name>
        <mode>pull</mode>
    </queue>
</queue-entries>

Answer (score 0):

My fault, it was saving the params, but when I did taskHolder.toString() it returned params as []. But List> entries = taskHolder.extractParams(); returned a list of enties with the data I had set in the params